# Why I'm Getting Null Object Reference Error?

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

i'm trying to retrieve data from firebase database i have finished the code with everything except for 1 minor error which every time i click to go to profile activity i'm getting this error: 
"Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.example.logindesign.Users.getFullName()' on a null object reference"

Here's is my profile activity code. i'm getting the error when i'm calling mName.setText("Name: "+ users.getFullName());

```
package com.example.logindesign;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.Objects;

public class Profile extends AppCompatActivity {

    FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    FirebaseUser user;
    FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
    DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    ImageView imageView;
    TextView mUsername, phoneNo, mEmail,  mName;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.profile_layout);


        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
        firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference(firebaseAuth.getUid());

        imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        mUsername = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        phoneNo = findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        mEmail = findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        mName = findViewById(R.id.textView3);


        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Users users = dataSnapshot.getValue(Users.class);

                mName.setText("Name: "+ users.getFullName());
                mUsername.setText("Username: "+users.getmUserName());
                mEmail.setText("Email: "+users.getEmail());
                phoneNo.setText("Phone No: "+users.getMobileNumber());


            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });




    }
}
```

and this is my Users Activity Code

```
package com.example.logindesign;

public class Users {

    public String fullName;
    public String mUserName;
    public String email;
    public String mobileNumber;

    public Users(){

    }

    public Users(String fullName, String mUserName, String email, String mobileNumber) {
        this.fullName = fullName;
        this.mUserName = mUserName;
        this.email = email;
        this.mobileNumber = mobileNumber;
    }

    public String getFullName() {
        return fullName;
    }

    public void setFullName(String fullName) {
        this.fullName = fullName;
    }

    public String getmUserName() {
        return mUserName;
    }

    public void setmUserName(String mUserName) {
        this.mUserName = mUserName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getMobileNumber() {
        return mobileNumber;
    }

    public void setMobileNumber(String mobileNumber) {
        this.mobileNumber = mobileNumber;
    }
}
```

any idea on what's causing this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line

```
Users users = dataSnapshot.getValue(Users.class);
```

returns null.
So your `users` object is null and the follow-up-line

```
mName.setText("Name: "+ users.getFullName());
```

causes the `NullReferenceException`

The solution is

```
Users users = dataSnapshot.getValue(Users.class);
if (users != null) {
    mName.setText("Name: "+ users.getFullName());
    mUsername.setText("Username: "+users.getmUserName());
    mEmail.setText("Email: "+users.getEmail());
    phoneNo.setText("Phone No: "+users.getMobileNumber());
} else {
    // write a log, write something else to the text boxes...
}
```

Maybe you need to check whether `dataSnapshot` even contains data about users? What else could have changed?

To me it looks like you blindly accept that callback without checks *what* has changed. Maybe this even triggers when data is deleted? Maybe there is other data contained in the snapshot, but not `Users`?

Comment: Ok now the error is gone, Thank you for that. But the data from database is not showing now.

Comment: you need to find out, why ``.getValue`` returns null. Read the docs, how this snapshot is structured. how you can query it correctly and how to find out, which contents it can hold. currently it does _not_ hold objects that are of ``Users.class`` type